# iphone sdk How to play DTMF audio file during a phone communication

Tags: iphone, audio, dtmf

I need to create an application that interact with a telecom company.
The end user make some choice in the application and after that we compose a number that include DTMF tone after a pause (,) to call the corresponding departement.
But my problem is here: composing DTMF digit take too much time about one second per digit.
 It's very very to slow if we need to add 10 DTMF digit.

SO my question: Is it possible to record the x DTMF's (0-9) in audio files and play them fast within the audio stream of the call to speed up the sending of DTMF's?

Edit:
Maybe my question was not explained in a very clear maneer but i don't create DTMF tone myself i just add some number after a pause. like that:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:003299887766,1234556890"]];
```

Comment: One second to generate a DTMF tone sounds too long - maybe you could speed up that code.  Try posting it in another question, maybe someone here can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is not possible to send shorter DTMF tones from iPhone.

One way to say bout it to apple is to use the feedback form: http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html